# Update atrribute value on click in dynamic table cell span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I make the Up buttons to update the attribute value? When I increase the count fx to 5 and then decrease it with Down buttons to 2, and then increase it again, it does not increase from the current value of attr value wich is 2 but continues from 5. I just don't know how to update it after Down button has been clicked. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/j9vnbcf0/8/)

```
$(function() {
    var plus = $('.up');
    var minus = $('.down');
    $(plus).each(function(index, element) {
        var count= $(element).closest('tr').find('.times').attr('data-myval');
        $(element).click(function() {
            count++;
            $(element).closest('tr').find('.times').attr('data-myval', count);
            $(element).closest('tr').find('.times').text(count +' x');
        });
    });
    $(minus).each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).click(function() {
            var count= $(element).closest('tr')
             .find('.times').attr('data-    myval');
            count--;
            parseInt($(element).closest('tr')
            .find('.times').attr('data-myval',count))
            $(element).closest('tr').find('.times').text(count +' x');
            if (count<2) {  
                $(element).closest('tr').find('.times').text('');
            }
            if (count < 1) {
                $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the `count`inside the `click` event for the `up` button:

```js
$(function() {
var plus = $('.up');
var minus = $('.down');
$(plus).each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).click(function() {
        var count= $(element).closest('tr').find('.times').attr('data-myval');
        count++;
        $(element).closest('tr').find('.times').attr('data-myval', count);
        $(element).closest('tr').find('.times').text(count +' x');
    });
});
$(minus).each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).click(function() {
        var count= $(element).closest('tr')
         .find('.times').attr('data-    myval');
        count--;
        parseInt($(element).closest('tr')
        .find('.times').attr('data-myval',count))
        $(element).closest('tr').find('.times').text(count +' x');
        if (count<2) {  
            $(element).closest('tr').find('.times').text('');
        }
        if (count < 1) {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        }
    });
});
});
```

I hope that helps :D

Answer (score 2):

I refactored your code to avoid putting click handlers inside of a loop.  jQuery lets you listen to click events on a per class basis without expressly defining each one.

The contents of each function is largely unchanged, I just saved the elements we need to look up in variables to avoid looking them up repeatedly.

Your problem in the code posted was `count` being set outside of the click handler.  That logic has been moved inside of the `.up` click handler.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrkw2k3t/)

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $('.up').on('click', function(){
    var count = $(this).closest('tr').find('.times');
    var curVal = Number(count.attr('data-myval'));
    count.attr('data-myval', curVal + 1);
    count.text(curVal + 1 + ' x');
  })

  $('.down').on('click', function(){
    var count = $(this).closest('tr').find('.times');
    var curVal = Number(count.attr('data-myval'));
    curVal--;
    count.attr('data-myval', curVal);
    count.text(curVal + ' x');

    if (curVal < 2) {   
      count.text('');
    }
    if (curVal < 1) {
      $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I like to be introduced to different ways.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are setting the count outside of the onclick function

```
var count= $(element).closest('tr').find('.times').attr('data-myval');
```

So the count may hold the previous value that was set when the last up was pressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hate when I can't see simple things as such.

Answer (score 1):

You just don't need to go through for `.each` function for each `plus/minus` btns, simply call `.click` function on them directly, it works that way-

JS-

```
$(function() {
    var plus = $('.up');
    var minus = $('.down'); 
        $(plus).click(function() {
    var count= $(this).closest('tr').find('.times').attr('data-myval');
            count++;
//          console.log(count);
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.times').attr('data-myval', count);
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.times').text(count +' x');
        });
    $(minus).click(function() {
            var count= $(this).closest('tr').find('.times').attr('data-myval');
            count--;
            parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('.times').attr('data-myval',count))
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.times').text(count +' x');
            if (count<2) {  
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.times').text('');
            }
            if (count < 1) {
                $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            }
    });
});
```

Here goes the updated link-

https://jsfiddle.net/j9vnbcf0/14/

Comment: I am sorry to say but your suggestion does not work. I guess the each() function is necessary?

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake, the link wasn't updated ;), here is the updated link with same solution being working-

https://jsfiddle.net/j9vnbcf0/14/

Answer (score 1):

grab the value first in count variable then increment i update your jsfiddle, i hope its helpful for you

```
var count = $(element).closest('tr').find('.times').attr('data-myval');
        count++;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j9vnbcf0/13/

Comment: Perfect, I am greatfull.